# Drivers for AMD Radeon HD 7550M on Sony Vaio?

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, vaio

I was trying to install Ubuntu for the first time in my life on my Sony Vaio.

I tried at first to Boot from a USB Drive, and it works perfectly.
After installing Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, I got a few issues.

It won't start anymore, all starts are ending up with a blurring screen, so I'm thinking, it's a graphic driver issue. I have the AMD Radeon HD 7550M on my Sony Vaio. When it is so, how can I solve this problem? I only have the ISO File from the Ubuntu Website and can not edit or put any Driver Files on it.

Answer (score 0):

This card uses outdated drivers and support is for Ubuntu 14.04. Perhaps it would work from the tty console <ctrl+alt+f3> and  ran commands:

```
 export DRI_PRIME=1
 startx
```

Comment: Is `startx` still relevant on an Ubuntu system? I thought Ubuntu was using Wayland these days.

Comment: It's hard to say what it's like with Ubuntu, X11 certainly won't disappear that quickly

Comment: @terdon I believe 22.04 ships with Wayland enabled as default, but I also believe that it is 22.04, wich generates quite a few questions on this site, like this does not work, or that I cannot customize, and the standard go-to answer is: switch to X  —which Ubuntu 22.04 also ships as standard— on the gdm login page. In fact, the recommendation of reverting to X is so prevalent that I always wonder how it feels for Wayland devs to have created this new system because the predecessor (X) is "so problematic", but they cannot get forward enough to escape this "2 redundant systems" situation.